# Need a PHP echo to produce a text hyperlink on buffer

Tags: php, forms, buffer, echo

I have a php form on my site. The form ultimately produces an article submitted by the user.

One of the data fields in the form, is a drop down menu so the user can select which publication they represent.

Currently, the form works if I am only trying to display the name of their publication.

However... I would also like that name to be a clickable link to their respective publication.

In an attempt to achieve this, I set my form up like this:

```
    Form: <select name="publication" id="publication">
          <option value="http://www.espn.com">ESPN</option>
          <option value="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</option>
          <option value="http://www.abcnews.com">ABC</option>
          <option value="http://www.cbsnews.com">CBS</option>
          <option value="http://www.foxnews.com">FOX</option>
          </select>
```

And the echo is set up like this:

```
    Echo:

   <?php $publication  = htmlspecialchars($_POST['publication']); echo $publication; ?>
```

Unfortunately, the result produces the full URL instead of the Text Link I am trying to achieve.

Not sure how I am supposed to code the form or the echo to achieve the desired clickable text link.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$_POST['publication']` is going to be the chosen `<option>`'s `value`, not the display name.

If you want to display the link along with the name, consider encoding the list of publications into a static array, then outputting that:

```
$publications = [
    "media1" => "link",
    "media2" => "link"
]

if (array_key_exists($_POST["publication"], $publications)) {
    echo '<a href="' . $publications[$_POST["publication"]] . '">' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["publication"]) . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: So.. in your suggestion tyteen... don't include the link portion in the form at all then, but set up the reference within the echo array?

name=link?

Comment: This produced all sorts of code errors when I tried to insert it into my code.

Comment: What errors are you getting? (The array definition syntax is PHP 5.4+; if you're not on PHP 7 you should really be upgrading.)

Comment: This was the solution, inserted in the form:


        <option value="<a href='http://example1.com'>Example1</a>">Example1</option>

Answer (score 0):

It is taking the value option, not the innerHTML. One solution is to make the value the following:

```
<a href='http://example.org'>Example</a>
```

Note: You may need to escape characters for this to work.

Comment: This seems to be the simple solution I was seeking. I will try this and come back to post results. Thanks guys.

Comment: Unfortunately... simply inserting the example above, did not work. It produced a result of <a. Nothing more

Comment: Try removing the htmlspecialcharactors thing. That might be the issue.

Comment: That may work on the php echo side. But inserting what you provided into the form itself is producing code errors in itself.